# How can I prevent cloning a git repository from specified user?

Tags: git

We are using git for our scm repository with sshd protocol.
How can I avoid a particular user cloning my git repository.

Is there any way to block only specified user and enable again? 
Without modify the system like (chgrp) or (chmod).

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant the `ssh` protocol, not `sshd`. This is more a file permission issue than anything else, so you will probably be dealing with filesystem permissions in one way or another.

I suppose you want to completely prevent access to your repository from this user, not just cloning. The simplest thing is probably to prevent ssh logins from that user.

You could also use a tool such as `Gitolite`, which makes it very easy to manage various repositories and their users.

Then, as you mentioned, the only real way to do access control with ssh is by changing file permissions. If you don't want to use `chgrp`, would a combination of `chmod`, `chown`, and [ACL](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists)s be the solution you are looking for?

You will probably have to differentiate this user from the others by putting them in a separate group, if you don't want to manually add every other user. If that's not a problem, you can however deny access to everyone, then allow everyone back (except the specified user) with some ACL.